# Differences between two images

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

Using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETZ0K.jpg) image as a refernce I want to find the dirty spot at the bottom of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kmW7.jpg) image.

I was able to turn second image to the same scale and orientation and now trying fo find the spot using [`absdiff`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#absdiff) but since images are not perfectly matchet I have edges on the [diff image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cF7I.jpg).

I'm thinking that instead of difference between pixels with same coordinates I need find minimal difference in an area like n by n pixels. So the question is: does OpenCV have something buitin for that and/or is there better solution to the problem?

**EDIT**: Solution using [`threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) and [`erode`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode):

```cs
public static Image<Bgr, Byte> Diff(Image<Bgr, Byte> image1,
                                    Image<Bgr, byte> image2,
                                    int erodeIterations=2)
{
    return Diff(image1, image2, new Bgr(50, 50, 50), erodeIterations);
}

public static Image<Bgr, Byte> Diff(Image<Bgr, Byte> image1, 
                                    Image<Bgr, byte> image2,
                                    Bgr thresholdColor,
                                    int erodeIterations)
{

    var diff = image1.AbsDiff(image2);
    diff = diff.ThresholdToZero(thresholdColor);
    diff = diff.Erode(erodeIterations);
    return diff;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about OpenCV, but solving this problem shouldn't be difficult. Align the two images and find the difference image as you've already done. Use a NxN sliding window across the difference image, and compute the number of pixels that are *significantly* different within the window i.e. ignore differences of up to say 10 grey levels. Find the maxima of these sums over the entire image, and this should highlight what you need.

Comment: Issue is that images may never align perfectly since there are always some errors in homography matrix used for perspective transform.

Comment: True, but with small misalignments, you should only get edges in the difference image for regions where the images are supposed to match. Where there is visible noise, you'll get a whole patch of high intensities in the difference image. In your code, you are finding the minimum difference in a region. I suggest you change this to count the number of significantly different pixels, and then find the maxima.

Comment: > suggest you change this to count the number of significantly different pixels, and then find the maxima
That basically `erode` over `absdiff`. Worked very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a similarity map where each pixel will be assinged with the histogram comparison value calculated on an n by b area focused on each pixel.

Comment: Is there something built-in for that?